# Grouping tables in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

How do I group a set of tables or label them together?

In our project, each user has two separate tables allocated for them. I need to group all users tables separately.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could use SQL Server Schemas to create logical separation of database objects (tables,views,stored procedures,functions,triggers etc.).

See the Microsoft Books Online Reference: [User-Schema Separation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx)

Using this method, you could then group related tables into the same schema.

Comment: @Tom H: Dude come on why are modifying my post spelling from British to American English :-)

Comment: Hey, I stopped changing "optimise" and "colour", I didn't realize that "seperate" was a British spelling. I thought it was just a common misspelling. :)

A quick search turned this up from those blokes over at Oxford: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/page/spellingcommonmisp/common-misspellings;jsessionid=D38660456AB0B89CFB410B03FC50E8CB

Comment: Bah what do they know anyway :-)

Comment: @TomH a lot of the s vs z differences between english and american are also misconceptions. There was a common misconception that *z* was the filthy american way, and so people would complain to newspapers that they were using the bastardized americanisms. The correct use is to check the etymology of the word - if it comes from latin or greek, then use z. If the root came via french, then take the french form - s. This is a pain to do all the time though. Newspapers then decided to use the "s" form - appeasing the grumpy (wrong) readers was easier than telling them they were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create another table to track what tables are allocated to whom. You can save Object Id of the tables with the User's ID.

Comment: I already have that. My problem now is that it's all displayed totally mixed up with the other core tables in Management Studio.